# Show that the adjusted values for 2x2 tables under the assumption of independence have the same absolute value

Tags: self-study, residuals, contingency-tables

I am trying to show that, for 2x2 tables, under the assumption of independence, that all four adjusted residuals have the same absolute value.

Adjusted residual: $r_{ij}=\dfrac{n_{ij}-\hat{u_{ij}}}{\sqrt{ \hat{u_{ij}}(1-P_{i+})(1-P_{+j})}}$

where $n_{ij}$ is the observed cell count, and $\hat{u_{ij}}=\dfrac{n_{i+}n_{+j}}{n}$ is the expected cell count, under the assumption of independence.

So far I have:

$r_{11}=\dfrac{n_{11}-\dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}}{n}}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}}{n}(1-\dfrac{n_{1+}}{n})(1-\dfrac{n_{+1}}{n})}}=\dfrac{n_{11}-\dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}}{n}}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n}}}$

$r_{12}==\dfrac{n_{12}-\dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+2}}{n}}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n}}}$

$r_{21}==\dfrac{n_{21}-\dfrac{n_{2+}n_{+1}}{n}}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n}}}$

$r_{22}==\dfrac{n_{22}-\dfrac{n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n}}{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n_{1+}n_{+1}n_{2+}n_{+2}}{n}}}$

So I just need to show that the absolute values of the numerators are the same. I can show this is true if i pick some random values for the 2x2 table, but how do I show that it is true in general? Thanks

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: All the denominators are the same.  Since this conclusion is correct, then algebra (along with the definitions of the $n_{1+}$ *etc.*) *must* show that all the numerators are the same up to sign.  Why not just do the algebra then?

Answer (score 2):

Just some simplification might help. The denominators are all the same, so you might scratch those... and keep in mind that 
$$n=n_{11}+n_{12}+n_{21}+n_{22}$$
Similarly, you could write $n$ as the sum of either the row totals or the column totals, for example,
$$n=n_{1+}+n_{2+}$$
Also, you can write each row total as a sum of the row entries, for example, 
$$n_{1+} = n_{11}+n_{12}$$

Using these facts, it seems like your answer will fall out...